# avoid newlines after menu-choice widget and/or after %v

Tags: widget

I'm using menu-choice elisp widgets, and I find that a newline is inserted after each one, unlike say an editable-field widget.

I would like to place multiple menu-choice widgets side-by-side (like a kind of very simple menu bar), like so:

`Menu: Value  Menu: Value  Menu: Value`

Is this possible?

EDIT: here's an example of two widgets that print on two separate lines that it'd like to print on the same line:

```lisp
(defun lem-ui-return-widgets (list)
  "Return a list of item widgets for each item, a string, in LIST."
  (cl-loop for x in list
           collect `(item :tag ,x :value ,x)))

(defun lem-ui-widget-format (str &optional binding)
  "Return a widget format string for STR, its name."
  (concat "%[" (propertize str 'face 'lem-ui-widget-face)
          "%]: %v"
          binding))

;; then in a display function:
;; (these two widgets print on separate lines,
;; regardless of whether a format function is used or not)
(widget-create 'menu-choice
               :tag "Listing"
               :value type
               :args (lem-ui-return-widgets lem-listing-types)
               :help-echo "Select a listing type"
               :format (lem-ui-widget-format "Listing" "C-c C-c")
               :notify (lem-ui-widget-notify-fun :sort))
(widget-create 'menu-choice
               :tag "Sort"
               :value sort
               :args (lem-ui-return-widgets lem-sort-types)
               :help-echo "Select a sort type"
               :format (lem-ui-widget-format "Sort" "C-c C-s")
               :notify (lem-ui-widget-notify-fun :listing-type))

(widget-minor-mode)
```

Also, when providing a formatting function, with the aim of adding some some text after the "%v" (value), I find that it also adds a newline following the value itself. Is it possible to add text after the %v on the same line?

like so:
`Menu: Value [C-c C-c]`

my very simple format function (also from edit above):

```lisp
(defun lem-ui-widget-format (str &optional binding)
  "Return a widget format string for STR, its name."
  (concat "%[" (propertize str 'face 'lem-ui-widget-face)
          "%]: %v"
          binding))
```

EDIT: the "binding" arg in the above, which I hand something like "C-c C-c" to, also prints on a separate line, below the widget that I am formatting. I would like it to be beside the widget.

EDIT 2: moreover, if i remove "%v" from the format function, i am able to print the two menu-choice widgets on the same line, so it looks like the "%v" is the cause of the both the issues i am describing.

String-trim doesn't work here, as it is only once the value is inserted into the format string that the newline is added.

Comment: Can you show us a complete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I added some more details, does that help? The example from the Widget manual also inserts a newline: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/widget.html#Programming-Example.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it's possible, and the trick is only that you need wrangle the `:format` argument not of the `menu-choice` widget, but its `item` or `choice-item` children, as that is there the newline is snuck in to the machinery.

example `:format "%[%v%] "`

Source: emacs bug email list widget expert [Bug#69457](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69457).